# Nvidia GT 440 exceeds max temperature

Tags: graphics-card, temperature, nvidia-geforce

I have an NVIDIA Geforce GT 440 installed on my system. A problem suddenly exists a few weeks ago whenever I play games such as C.O.D blackops, A. Creed 3 or even NBA 2k13 suddenly shutsdown my system and restarts. I check on the HW monitor to identify what component causes the problem and found out that the temperature of my video card exceeds the maximum temperature it has on its spec (http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-440-channel/specifications). It even reached 102°C.

I tried cleaning up the hardware but of no improvement. Please advise.

Comment: If your hardware is reaching 102 Celsius it means your cooling isn't working.  My guess the GPU heatsink's fan isn't working.

Comment: but the fan is rotating...

Comment: At what RPM?  I had a CPU heatsink fan break and it spun at about a max 300 RPM because it was well broken.  Either your GPU is not supported by those games or its broken but it reaching that temperature is NOT normal.